# How to get selected text printer Name from selected option drop down on post method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I work on asp.net razor page .I face Issue I can't get selected text from selected options drop down on page model on post method

on page html

```
<form id="FrmShelfLabelPrintrSetup" method="post" asp-page-handler="PrintAdc" >
<select id="PrinterName-select" asp-for="SelectedPrinterId" name="selectprinterid" class="form-select" style="margin-left:3px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
                            <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                            @foreach (var printer in Model.PrinterList)
                            {

                                <option value="@printer.UserPC">@printer.PrinterName</option>


                            }
                        </select>
<button id="PrintAdc" type="submit" name="PrintAdcButton" value="PrintAdc" style="width:100px;margin-top:7px;" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

</form>
```

Now How to get printer name selected text on post method on Page Model

```
public class LabelPrintingModel : PageModel
 {
public LabelPrintingModel()
 {

 }
 public void OnPostPrintAdc()
 {
           //How to get printer name selected text here 
 }
}
```

**Updated post**

so are there are any solution for pass selected text printer name direct  from html to page model without using database to fetch it or use printer name as value and text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get printer name selected text on post method on Page Model

There are two ways:

Option 1:
Change the option value into : `value="@printer.PrinterName"`

```
 <option value="@printer.PrinterName">@printer.PrinterName</option>
```

result:

[image]

Option 2:

```
 var name = from s in PrinterList
                       where s.UserPC == selectprinterid
                       select s.PrinterName;
```

**Update:**

```
public class LabelPrintingModel : PageModel
 { 
public List<xxxxxxx> PrinterList{ get; set; }
public LabelPrintingModel()
 {
   PrinterList= //get your data
 }
 public void OnPostPrintAdc()
 {
           //How to get printer name selected text here 
 var name = from s in PrinterList
                       where s.UserPC == selectprinterid
                       select s.PrinterName;
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply can i pass selected text direct from html to page model  because i need both properties on page model text as PrinterName and value as UserPC so first option is not proper for me and second option i o to database although i already loaded value and text

Comment: so are there are any solution to pass it direct selected text from html to page model

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz  You can set your PrinterList as global variable  (not in the get method),  then you can load value and text one time, no need to reloaded again.

Comment: can you please show to me that on answer please by code it seems it is good for me

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz  Have a look at my update, hope it can help you.

Comment: ok i accepted but if there are more best choice for that please provide me